# How to check if a file is equal to another file in a directory with paperclip

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, paperclip

I have a rails application where one uploads a song and I am trying to compare that song to all other songs in the asset directory. If the song is equal, I'd like to delete the upload and just route all queries to the master song.

I was thinking of making an association where a master song has many user song uploads, but by default the master song id the user associates is nil. How would I check if the songs in the assets are equal, and how to delete the song and route the requests to the master songs.

Here is my db for user_song_uploads:

```
class CreateUserSongUploads < ActiveRecord::Migration
  def change
    create_table :user_song_uploads do |t|
        t.integer :user_id
        t.has_attached_file :song
            :url => "/assets/user_song_uploads/:id/",
            :path =>  "#{rails.root}/assets/user_song_uploads/:id/",
      t.timestamps
      t.string :artist
      t.string :album
      t.string :title
    end
  end
end
```

My master_song db:

```
 t.has_attached_file :m_song
     :url => "/assets/master_songs/:id",
     :path =>  "#{rails.root}/assets/master_songs/:id",
```

Any ideas? Thank you so much.

Comment: What do you mean by equal? Same song, bit rate, format? What if two songs are the same and one is an mp3 and the other is m4a?

Comment: I'm going to use a function to compare bits and if the song is more than say, 90% similar they are the same song, but that will be easy to implement, so I'm working on this first. Thanks

Answer (score 1):

File level comparison:

Make a md5/sha1 checksum of the file and keep them at db, when next upload comes, when upload finish compare the checksum first and if same just link them.

This is similar to ZFS file system deduplication.